# Is the union of two cartesian products equal to the product of their unions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can we prove that
$$(A \times B)\cup (C \times D) = (A \cup C) \times (B \cup D)  \;?$$
If my understanding is correct, we cannot prove because we do not know if $A \times B$ and $C \times D$ share common elements or not. Please tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful.

Comment: @Joe K +1 for a good title choice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** What do you get for $A=\{1\}$, $B=\{2\}$, $C=\{3\}$, $D=\{4\}$?
(Which is almost the simplest case you can think of.)

Comment: LHS: ( {1,2} , {3,4}  )
RHS : ( {1,2} , {1,4}, {3,2} , {3,4} )

Comment: @Joe K, It is not. LHS is $\{(1,2),(3,4)\}$ while the RHS is $\{(1,2),(1,4),(3,2),(3,4)\}.$

Comment: @JoeK The curly brackets $\{\}$ are normally used for sets. If $(x,y)$ is your notation for ordered pair, you should write $\{(1,2),(3,4)\}$ on the LHS.

Comment: Oh thanks for the correction :)